# How does Apache resolve 'localhost'

Tags: apache

With a regular apache setup, typing `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` into the browser will result in apache trying to serve files out of `~/public_html`. I want to know how the `~` part is resolved, since no information about the system user is included in the **http request**, and multiple users could be using the same apache service at the same time, so it can't be resolved based on *"current logged in user"*. So how does apache know how to resolve `~`?

Answer (score 0):

Apache has the [`User`](https://devdocs.io/apache_http_server/mod/mod_unixd#user) directive available.

> The `User` directive sets the user ID as which the server will answer
>   requests. In order to use this directive, the server must be run
>   initially as `root`. If you start the server as a non-root user, it
>   will fail to change to the lesser privileged user, and will instead
>   continue to run as that original user.

Answer (score 0):

There're several different concepts involved.

- The browser resolves all names into IP addresses using the underlying operating system DNS resolver, which is normally a combination of a text file for local address and a network query to a remote DNS server (together with the appropriate caching).
- `localhost` is a standard alias for 127.0.0.1 (in other words, local machine). Anybody else who loads `localhost` in his browser will connect to his machine, not yours.
- `~` is syntactic sugar used by Unix shells to represent current user's home directory.
- Default Apache settings will not load anything from home directories. However, many third-party packages change this.
- There's an optional Apache module ([mod_userdir](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_userdir.html)) that offers automated custom sites from home directories nested in main site. The syntax is uses (`http://example.com/~john`) mimics the `~` shell syntax (but it's a different thing) and has nothing to do with `localhost`.